# Isomorphic symmetric squares of non-isomorphic curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Is it possible for the symmetric squares of a pair of non-isomorphic curves $C_1, C_2$ defined over a field $K$ to be isomorphic?

EDIT: as the user @abx has mentioned, there exist such examples in the case of genus 2 curves. I would like to add further restrictions which correspond to the special case I am interested in: what if $C_1$ and $C_2$ are both smooth plane quartic curves?

Comment: Yes. There are many examples of pairs of non-isomorphic curves of genus 2 whose Jacobians are isomorphic. Therefore their symmetric squares are isomorphic, because they are obtained by blowing up one point in their Jacobian.

Comment: What if I am particularly interested in projective plane quartics then? Is it still the case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $C_1$ and $C_2$ are smooth plane quartics and
$$
f \colon S^2C_1 \to S^2C_2
$$
is an isomorphism then it induces an isomorphism
$$
J(C_1) \cong 
\mathrm{Alb}(S^2C_1) \stackrel{\mathrm{Alb}(f)}\to 
\mathrm{Alb}(S^2C_2) \cong J(S^2C_2)
$$
is an isomorphism that takes the theta-divisor of the first (equal to the image of $S^2C_1$ under the Albanese morphism) to the theta-divisor of the second (equal to the image of $S^2C_2$ under the Albanese morphism). Thus, we have an isomorphism of Jacobians compatible with principal polarizations, hence, by Torelli theorem, an isomorphism of the curves.

Comment: I think that essentially the same argument works for hyperelliptic curves of genus 3 as well (using that $S^2C$ contains a unique rational curve in this case).

Comment: A similar result for curves of arbitrary genus was proved by Martens in the 60's. See "An extended Torelli theorem", Amer. J. Math, 87 (1965), pp. 257–261. There is also a more recent result of Ciliberto and Sernesi for symmetric products of degree greater than the genus.)